# Is it possible to process audio from other apps in android

Tags: android, audio

I would like to create an audio enhancing filter for Android that will be available for all apps (mostly music players, but maybe also youtube, web, etc.).
Is there a way to achieve that (assuming I know how to process the audio in real time).
Think of my software as something that sits between all audio output from apps and in front of the hardware.

Comment: do u mean this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html or any of those http://www.androidcentral.com/best-equalizer-apps-android ?

Comment: just to add to the comment. No from all the audios (that was removed on some android version), you have to choose which audio source the effect will be applied

Comment: Thank you Budius - yes, I was looking at the audiofx thing, and I would love to apply this to all audio, but willing to compromise... The situation is that I want to have my code present the GUI and do the actual processing, but the playback can be any other app (Media Player, music players, youtube, etc.)